# Python Backup file script problems

Tags: python, python-2.6

I've been working on a backup script below, copying files from one server to another, with several requirements. The code is below. Any help?  And I have a  sample test input.

```
import arcpy                                     # Import arcpy module
from arcpy import env                            # Import env module from arcpy
import os                                        # Import os module
import logging                                   # Import logging module
import shutil                                    # Import shutil module

inFile = "G:\data"                               # Input specified
outFile = "D:\data"                              # Output specified
backup = "D:\backup"                             # Intermediate backup file
logdirectory = "S:\backup_directory\log\*.log"                      
log = logging.getLogger("G:\data")               # Creates logger instance
hdlr = logging.FileHandler("G:\data\*.log")      # Creates FileHandler
# Creates Formatter    
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelName)s %(message)s")

hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)   # Attaches Formatter to FileHandler
logger.addHandler(hdlr)        # Attaches FileHandler to Logger
logger.setLevel(logging.NOTE)  # Sets logger note

inFile = open("G:\users\tchaney\TestInputFile.txt", "r")
# Opens the data file to be read, and assigns it to the variable, inFile
outFile = open("G:\users\tchaney\TestOutputFile.txt", "w")
# Opens a data output file to be written to, and assigns it to outFile

shutil.copyfile(logger, "D:\data\copy_[fileDate].log")
# Copy logfile to archive as "copy_[filedate].log"

#for "*.log" in "logdirectory"
# For loop to check current date, and returns files 7 days old or less
    #return(currDate - fileDate) <= 7
#logger.note("Log files updated")

# same as file.readline() - reads one line at a time into a string variable,
# loop to read, stop service, write, start service. 
for inLine in inFile:
    # Split each line, while removing the comma, and store each field
    service, srcFile, destFile = inLine.split(",")

    # If source exists, for each service in the array, stop the service
    if os.path.exists("srcFile"): 
        for service in inFile[:]:                                       
            os.system("AGSSOM.EXE -x")        

        # If destination variable exists, copy destination to backup, and remove destination
        if os.path.exists("destFile"): 
            #arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True  (needed with shutil?)
            shutil.copyfile("G:\data\*", "D:\backup\*")
            os.remove("destFile")
        else:
            logger.note("Filename did not exist prior to copy")

        shutil.copyfile("srcFile", "destFile") # Copy source to destination

        # If destination does not exist, copy backup to destination, and add logger note
        if not os.path.exists("destFile"): 
            shutil.copyfile("D:\backup\*", "D:\data\*")
            logger.note("[filename] copied from backup")

        for service in inFile[:]: # For each service in the array, start the service    
            os.system("AGSSOM.EXE -s")
    else: # If the source is not found, add logger note
        logger.note("Source not found")

inFile.close() # Close input file
outFile.close() # Close output file
```

Comment: I took the liberty of reformating your code. **That level of comments is insane**: At *best*, it will confuse everyone. At worst, comments and code will go out of sync.

Comment: kinda hard to say anything without the errors you are facing, don't you think?

Comment: What is going wrong with the script that you need help with? Posting code and saying "any help?" isn't a question.

Comment: One more thing: **You did not actually ask a question.** You just dumped some code and expect us to not only derive the requirements from the code, but also find a mistake in it. Also, you mention input data, but don't actually give any. Finally, what is the relevance of AGSSOM.EXE? Why don't you include that file in the question, or, alternatively, remove the calls to it in the code? **Please make sure that your question contains an [SSCE](http://sscce.org/)**.

Answer (score 2):

One prime mistake is giving a `glob` argument to [`shutil.copyfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile).

```
shutil.copyfile("D:\backup\*", "D:\data\*")
```

should read

```
import glob
for fn in glob.glob("D:\\backup\\*"):
  shutil.copyfile(fn, "D:\\data")
```

Similarly, the following line is strange:

```
hdr = logging.FileHandler("G:\data\*.log")
```

it should probably be something along the lines of

```
hdr = logging.FileHandler("G:\\data\\my_application.log")
```

Comment: Phihag, well, thanks for some help between the arrogant and belittling language.  It was amazing to read some of the arrogance in the responses!  Yes, I forgot to include the error messages at the bottom.  They were my question.  But for someone who knows little about Python and has NEVER used these forums before, I find it amazing that people would respond in such a negative fashion.  I assumed these forums would meant to help beginner Python users, not bash them for overuse of comments!  And AGSSOM.EXE is used to open and close a service, as on a server, clearly.  Look it up.

Comment: And are code examples only allowed if they are very general questions? No one might ever possibly use this example to back up some data? It was closed because it was too specific in nature?

Comment: @user906596 Sorry, but I wasn't intending to belittle you or be arrogant. All I wanted to point out with the first paragraph is that the error might well be buried in the code, because it strays extremely far away from guidelines for good coding. This site welcomes any questions about programming, and we're happy to improve those questions (That's what [I did](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7935784/revisions)). However, to be able to answer a question, there has to be some question in the first place. I'm sorry, but I still fail to find one.

Comment: @user906596 You're more than welcome to provide code examples. However, you did not provide any, all you provided was a heap of code. A proper example should not be longer than 20 lines, and it should be [short, self-contained, and correct](http://sscce.org/). Unfortunately, the code in this question fails to met any of these criteria. Even worse, there's no mention of what you expect, what happened, or what platform you're on. I'd be guessing ArcGIS on Windows, but since you didn't tag your question with either of those, one can still assume it's a general Python question.

Comment: @user906596 As it stands, nobody can possibly answer your whole question, due to a collosal lack of information. For example, I gather from your code that to reproduce the problem - *which you still haven't told us* -, one would need not only a Windows system, Python, and ArcGIS, but also half a dozen directories and files. Additionally, since the `several requirements` are never fully explained, the only possible fully correct answer would need to determine the requirements, by calling your boss. That's just not feasible for an internet question. And we don't have the phone number.

Comment: I've figured it out on my own.  And next time, if I ever post on any forum, I'll be sure to follow the strict guidelines in place, explain everything in depth, and provide code with exacting detail.  This will surely provoke responses such as "A terrible question - it is far too complex!", doesn't follow rules, etc...  No, I did not post my question, and I did not post any more information.  Initially I assumed if someone wanted the sample input, etc, they would ask for it.  Since the post was closed, I assumed no one would be able to see it or comment on it, except the moderators. I give up.

Comment: @user906596 No offense, but who's being arrogant here? If your *question* does not contain an actual *question*, you *expect* someone to ask for details? And by the way, asking for details is what the stackoverflow community did (`kinda hard to say anything without the errors you are facing, don't you think?`, `What is going wrong with the script that you need help with`). Notice providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is about making the question *simpler*, not more complex. As I said, next to any stackoverflow question should contain code, and that code should be no more than 20 lines.

Comment: As I wrote above, my question was about the three error messages I forgot to include at the bottom. My issue is with the tone of the messages. For example, the immense raft I got concerning comments seemed both trivial and arrogant. And my code was too long to only put 20 lines...  But I should have included the three error messages I was getting, so people knew what my problem was.  It was the hostility in the responses (including your last response, in which you seem pretty upset) that I did not expect...  I assumed the community would realize I was new and respond accordingly.  My fault.

Comment: @user906596 Umm, so you're saying, that *everyone else is wrong* in not commenting every single line, and you are right in using comments sparingly, and to explain things not already present in the code? And forgive me, but I *still* can't find the error messages. About the code being too long: That's precisely the point; **you should have reduced the problem to a short excerpt**, as decribed on the [instructions I keep linking](http://sscce.org/). stackoverflow does not strive to discuss large programs. Imagine someone with a problem in a 1000 line program - would *you* be willing to answer?

Comment: No, I'm saying there might be a better way to put things than "As it stands, the code is a good candidate for TheDailyWTF for its overly verbose, trivial comments, commented code, and lack of a question" and "That level of comments is insane"... Maybe "BTW, generally people don't comment that much..."? And I would not be able to answer much on this site at all - that's why I posted here. I'm new to both programming and Python. And there will be no error messages posted. I have corrected them. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user906596 In response to the edit: No, I'm not upset. I'm sorry if my message conveyed that, that was not my intention (English isn't my first language, so I may accidentally introduce nuances that aren't there). The community *did* [correct the formatting mistakes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7935784/revisions), and *did* ask you both for the question you left out, and *did* ask you to provide a question one could possibly answer. [continued...]

Comment: [...] You still haven't posted the actual question (or simplified the code, or provided the answer you found). If you mistake justified criticism of code with hostility, stackoverflow is not the place for you.

Comment: @user906596 Yes, I agree that that paragraph can indeed be understood as offensive, and I should have left it out. Edited it out. `there will be no error messages posted` - I'm sorry, but you seem to misunderstand the concept of stackoverflow. We're interested in programming problems, and would love to have this (or any) question as a signpost **for someone else having the same problem**. The real value of stackoverflow is that many people may have a question, and it only needs to be answered once.

Comment: I will post the finished product (when completed), so that others may learn from it, of course.  We are all here to help one another.  I'm still ironing out the details, checking each step for bugs, making sure I meet all of the requirements.  If I get stuck with the smaller parts, I may re-post, using the standards specified in the link.  And again, thank you for your time and help.